# Rendering fat by sous vide

Tags: cooking-time, sous-vide, fat

I've seen that fat will render at 55-60 degrees centigrade using sous vide - but my question is how long that would be expected to take?

Comment: There's apparently something about rendering fats in the Thomas Keller Sous Vide cookbook. I don't have access to it right now, but if this doesn't get answered already, I can take a look later. If you have access to it, then check it out and maybe you can answer your own question :)

Comment: Some of this is going to depend on how much fat, and the original temperature of said fat when you start the process.

Comment: It is do-able, but one of the drawbacks is that the water trapped in the fat doesn't evaporate when you render sous vide, so you have to then separate the fat and water afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

Thomas Keller's cookbook "Under Pressure: Cooking Sous Vide" recommends 1:30 @ 85C for beef or duck fat, 1:00 @ 85C for marrow fat, and 0:45 @ 85C for foie gras fat.

Comment: Surely this is far too simplistic? The length of time for a ribeye Vs a rump joint is going to be different.